# [Authorize(Roles = "Manager") is not getting applied and it it act like AllowAnonymous

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

For some reason [Authorize] or [Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]  is not getting applied,
I get same result with or without them.

MY code is

```
  ` [Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
    public void OnGet()
    {
      var x = User.IsInRole("Manager"); 
    }`
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
;

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    });


builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy =>
        policy.RequireClaim("IsAdmin", "True"));

});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var serviceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
    await Seeder.Seed(serviceProvider);
}

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

```
`public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

`

anyone can see what is the issue here, am I missing something ?

I'm expecting to be redirected to the login page in case I'm not authorized to access that page,

Comment: try to put on top of the controller and check @bade

Answer (score 0):

```
[Authorize]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult View()
    {  }
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,SuperAdmin")]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {   }
    [Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]
    public ActionResult Delete()
    {   }
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]
    public ActionResult SpecialFeature()
    {   }
}
```

Comment: this is still not fully right, because I should be able to mark one of the method to be Authorize without defining the big controller, right ?